# Output not printed to file like supposed to using FileWriter

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

So my program compiles but when testing the early analysis I realized it does not print the file showing all the output. Can someone please show me why the file isn't being printed at all? Here's my code...

```
import java.io.*;    
import java.util.*;    

public class Analyzer     
{         

private static FileWriter stream;    
        private static BufferedWriter output;

    public static void start() throws IOException

{       
    int i = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int totalError = 0;
    final int SIZE = 40000;
    Response data[] = new Response[SIZE];

    stream = new FileWriter("apacheOut.txt");
    output = new BufferedWriter(stream);

    Scanner scan = new Scanner("access_log1.txt");
    scan.useDelimiter ("[-\t]+");
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) 
    {
        double address = scan.nextDouble();
        String date = scan.next();
        String request = scan.next();
        int status = scan.nextInt();
        int bytes = scan.nextInt();
        String refer = scan.next();
        String agent = scan.next();

        if (Integer.toString(status).substring(0, 1) == "4" || Integer.toString(status).substring(0, 1) == "5")
        {
            ErrorResponse er = new ErrorResponse (address, date, request, status, bytes, refer, agent);
            totalError++;
        }
        else
        {
            SuccessResponse sr = new SuccessResponse (address, date, request, status, bytes, refer, agent);
        }

        total++;
    }

    int numGet = 0;
    int numPost = 0;
    double numBytes = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++)
    {   
        double address = data[i].getAddress();
        String date = data[i].getDate();
        String request = data[i].getRequest();
        int status = data[i].getStatus();
        int bytes = data[i].getBytes();
        String refer = data[i].getRefer();
        String agent = data[i].getAgent();

        /** GET/POST count */
        if (request.substring(0,1) == "G")
        {   
            numGet++;
        }
        else if (request.substring(0,1) == "P")
        {
            numPost++;
        }

        /** Number of total bytes */
        numBytes = bytes++;
    }

    output.write("Warren Smith's Results");
    output.write("======================");
    output.write("The total number of requests in the file: " + total);
    output.write("The total number of GET requests: " + numGet);
    output.write("The total number of POST requests: " + numPost);
    output.write("The total number of bytes served: " + numBytes);
    output.write("The number & percentage of pages producing various status categorizations:" );
    output.write("    1xx Informational: ");
    output.write("    2xx Status: ");
    output.write("    3xx Redirection: ");
    output.write("    4xx Client Error: ");
    output.write("    5xx Server Error: ");
    output.write("The percentage and number of Windows-based clients: ");
    output.write("The percentage and number of bad requests: ");
    output.write("The percentage and number of clients that are Mozilla-based: ");
    output.write("The percentage and number of requests from the Googlebot: ");

    output.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use .equals() method to check if two strings are equals
change this

```
    if (Integer.toString(status).substring(0, 1) == "4" || Integer.toString(status).substring(0, 1) == "5")
```

to

```
if (Integer.toString(status).substring(0, 1).equals("4") || Integer.toString(status).substring(0, 1).equals( "5"))
```

Comment: This is irrelevant. This has nothing to do with whether the file is written to or not.

Answer (score 0):

No output at all? You're writing to `BufferedWriter output` which wraps `FileWriter stream`. However, you're only closing (and automatically flushing) the output stream. The FileWriter may buffer on its own, and if you terminate the program before that's finished writing it may never commit the changes to disk.

After `output.close();` try adding:

```
stream.flush();
stream.close();
```